# Can someone help me with this join

Tags: sql, join

I need it to give me me a total of 0 for week 33 - 39, but I'm really bad with joining 3 tables and I cant figure it out

Right now it only gives me an answer for dates that there are actual records in the tracker_weld_table.[image][image][image][image][image]

```
SELECT SUM(tracker_parts_archive.weight), 
WEEK(mycal.dt) as week 
FROM 
tracker_parts_archive, tracker_weld_archive 
RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT dt FROM calendar_table WHERE dt >= '2018-7-1' AND dt <= '2018-10-1') as mycal 
ON 
weld_worker = '133'AND date(weld_dateandtime) = mycal.dt 
WHERE 
tracker_weld_archive.tracker_partsID = tracker_parts_archive.id 
GROUP BY week
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your DBMS, table definition, sample input and expected output?

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Comment: 1. Comma has lower precedence than explicit joins. 2. Learn what left/right join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left/right table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of an outer join. A where that requires a right/left table column to be not null after a left/right join on, which you have, removes any rows extended by nulls, ie leaves only inner join on rows, ie "turns outer join into inner join". PS Please read re [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying for something like this:

```
SELECT WEEK(c.dt) as week, COALESCE(SUM(tpa.weight), 0)     
FROM calendar_table c left join 
     tracker_weld_archive tw
     on date(tw.weld_dateandtime) = c.dt left join
     tracker_parts_archive tp 
     on tw.tracker_partsID = tp.id and tp.weld_worker = 133
WHERE c.dt >= '2018-07-01' AND c.dt <= '2018-10-01' 
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week;
```

Notes:

- You want to keep all (matching) rows in the calendar table, so it should be first.
- All subsequent joins should be `LEFT JOIN`s.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- Write out the full proper date constant -- YYYY-MM-DD.  This is an ISO-standard format.
- I am guessing that `weld_worker` is a number, so single quotes are not needed for the comparison.

Comment: Gordon, This will work. it gives me every week like i want but instead of a sum of 0 it gives me null but that's definitely in the right direction.

Comment: I changed it a little more to include IFNULL(SUM(tpa.weight),0), now is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

First, lets start with understanding what you want..  You want totals per week.  This means there will be a "GROUP BY" clause (also for any MIN(), MAX(), AVG(), SUM(), COUNT(), etc. aggregates).  What is the group BY basis.  In this scenario, you want per week.  Leading to the next part that you want for a specific date range qualified per your calendar table.

I would start in order what WHAT filtering criteria first.  Also, ALWAYS TRY to identify all table( or alias).column in your queries so anyone after you knows where the columns are coming from, especially when multiple tables.  In this case "ct" is the ALIAS for "Calendar_Table"

```
SELECT
      ct.dt
   from
      calendar_table ct
   where
          ct.dt >= '2018-07-01' 
      AND ct.dt <= '2018-10-01'
```

Now, the above date looks to be INCLUSIVE of October 1 and looks like you are trying to generate a quarterly sum from July, Aug, Sept.  I would change to LESS than Oct 1.

Now, your calendar has many days and you want it grouped by week, so the WEEK() function gets you that distinct reference without explicitly checking every date.  Also, try NOT to use reserved keywords as final column names... makes for confusion later on sometimes. 
I have aliased the column name as "WeekBasis".  Here, I did a COUNT(*) just to show the total days and the group by showing it in context.

```
SELECT 
      WEEK( ct.dt ) WeekBasis,
      MIN( ct.dt ) as FirstDayOfThisWeek,
      MAX( ct.dt ) as LastDayOfThisWeek,
      COUNT(*) as DaysInThisWeek
   from
      calendar_table ct
   where
          ct.dt >= '2018-07-01' 
      AND ct.dt <= '2018-10-01'
   group by
      WEEK( ct.dt )
```

So, at this point, we have 1 record per week within the date period you are concerned,
but I also grabbed the earliest and latest dates just to show other components too.

Now, lets get back to your extra tables.  We know the dates in question, now need to
get the details from the other tables (which is lacking in the post.  You should post
critical components such as how tables are related via common / joined column basis.
How is tracker_part_archive related to tracker_weld_archive??

To simplify your query, you dont even NEED your calendar table as the welding
table HAS a date field and you know your range.  Just query against that directly.

IF your worker's ID is numeric, don't add quotes around it, just leave as a number.

```
SELECT 
      WEEK( twa.Weld_DateAndTime ) WeekBasis,
      COUNT(*) WeldingEntriesDone,
      SUM(tpa.weight) TotalWeight
   from
      tracker_weld_archive twa
         JOIN tracker_parts_archive tpa
            -- GUESSING on therelationship here.
            -- may also be on a given date too???
            -- all pieces welded by a person on a given date
            ON twa.weld_worker = tpa.weld_worker
            AND twa.Weld_DateAndTime = tpa.Weld_DateAndTime
   where
          twa.Weld_Worker = 133
      AND twa.Weld_DateAndTime >= '2018-07-01' 
      AND twa.Weld_DateAndTime <= '2018-10-01'
   group by
      WEEK( twa.Weld_DateAndTime )
```

IF you provide the table structures AND sample data, this can be refined a bit more for you.

Comment: Thank you, this was a good read, and you almost figured out how all my tables work even with the limited information I provided, I am sorry for that. after fixing the relationships in the twa.tracker_partsID = tpa.id your query ran just fine, however It gets me what I'm already getting.